# loading postgis functions into a PostgreSQL 8.3.7 database using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin, phppgadmin

I am trying to load postgis.sql files into a pgAdmin database (using psql) that has already been created so I can create a spatially enabled database.  I have confirmed that the language "plpgsql" already exists, but I cannot execute the following functions:

```
psql -d yourdatabase -f lwpostgis.sql;
psql -d yourdatabase -f lwpostgis_upgrade.sql;
psql -d yourdatabase -f spatial_ref_sys.sql;
```

I just get the generic "syntax error at or near...".

Maybe I am not formatting the line right, because from what I have read, this should work?  do I really need "psql"?  what does "-d" do?  I tried without psql in front of the commands and bupkiss.  Thoughts are appreciated...thanks.

Comment: pgAdmin is the GUI. You mean PostgreSQL? Add version numbers to involved software, please.

Comment: my bad; yes, I do mean PostgreSQL, version 8.3.7, psql version 9.1.4.

Comment: The commands you quote are meant to be input in a shell interpreter or cmd.exe if using MS-Windows. From bits of your question, it looks like you're already into some other program (presumably pgAdmin or psql itself) when you're typing this.

Comment: @Daniel - thank you for the info!  I am indeed typing these commands in psql from my computer.  The database, postGIS and PostgreSQL are on a server and computer down the hall.  pgAdmin is on my machine here...will this not be possible through psql?

Comment: Sure it's possible, I've submitted an answer to that effect but you need to leave pgAdmin out of the way. psql and pgAdmin are mutually exclusive.

Comment: gotcha - I was accessing psql through the pulgins menu in pgAdmin III

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-d yourdatabase` option connects to this database once psql has started.
The `-f file.sql` option says to load file.sql and execute all the SQL commands it contains.

If you're already inside `psql`, the equivalent commands would be:

`\c yourdatabase`:  connect to the db named `yourdatabase`.

`\i file.sql`: loads `file.sql` and execute all commands in it. It should be in the current path, otherwise specify a full path.

Comment: @ Daniel - thank you for the help.  I actually found out that the problem was I could not path to the server correctly.  I ended up having the individual files put on my computer and uploaded them using phpPgAdmin because psql didn't execute the files and gave me errors...lots of them.